# Add files to Doxygen group with addgroup, without modifying the code

Tags: doxygen

I have a project with a lot of .c files scattered.

They are pretty often doing things related to each other and as such i want to have them grouped in the resulting doxygen website. The problem is that the project has never used doxygen before, as such I cannot go into every file and add `\addtogroup Group A` in every file.

What i would like to to is to have a separate file where I could define the groupings, without modifying the source code. at least as a start. Is this possible?

Something like `Groupings.dox`

Which would contain the following:

```
File1 GroupA
File2 GroupA
File3 GroupB
```

Comment: This is not possible in doxygen.

Comment: Is there some other way i might go about getting things grouped up without touching the source?

Comment: Not really, and `INPUT_FILTER` would add lines i the code doxygen parses and this would disrupt the process of references etc. (lines don't correspond with the original anymore). Maybe the only thing is to define a page per group (`\page`, `\subpage`) with links to the files (but you, probably, have to decode the filenames in respect to the names used), in your code you would get something like `<a href="aa_8h.html">`

Comment: That is unfortunate, I guess I will have to live without it for now then.